# Shopify asset path in stylesheet?

Tags: shopify

How to reference the assets path in css?
Can I still use style.css.liquid?
Not sure how to create the link tag.

Tried various paths and using a .liquid extension to be able to use filters.

Comment: Not much clear about the question, and also shared the example code that you tried

Comment: tried creating {{ 'style.css.liquid' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}  to use {{ file.name | asset_url }} filter, but it didnt expand the liquid.
So I dont think liquid stylesheets are allowed anymore. 

in terms of hard-coded paths, I tried finding the cdn path, but found it difficult to do so. Also tried /assets/filename and ../assets/filename. 
Both gave 404s

Comment: if still able to create a .liquid css file it means you can use the liquid code inside.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo with dawn theme.

I have create a file name test.css.liquid and add it theme.liquid using `{{stylesheet_tag}}`

[image]

After it I have upload a image and add it to div background using liquid code into test.css.liquid.
[image]

and it works well, here is the frontend snapshot.
[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: ahh, I see. You're filename is test.css.liquid, but in your code you write test.css | asset_url, and shopify knows the correct file.
That was the part I was missing, TY!